# Imageresizer azure problems

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service, imageresizer

I'm using [ImageResizer.net](http://imageresizing.net/) library for image resizing on a site I've been working on.

I just pushed all the code to an azure website, and the images (stored in blobs) display locally with all my production config settings, but I just get 404 errors on the live site.

Any ideas why? I can give a link if that will help.

**Debug page output:**

It didn't paste well, linked [here](http://www.midwestcointrader.com/resizer.debug.ashx)

**Figured out how to turn on error logging in azure. This looks like the important message:**

[image]

[image]

**Edit 1**
After looking at the debug page again just now it seems like it doesn't recognize I have a lisence for the cloud bundle maybe. Does any one know how to apply a lisence in the resizer library? Locally it picks up that I have a lisence but not out in azure.

Comment: The AzureReader plugin isn't even loading in this scenario... Also, indent the debug page, very hard to read line-wrapped...

Comment: Ok, I've included a link to it instead of pasting in. Now, do you have any ideas why the plugin isn't loading. What would be useful to post to help figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that every time I came back to the site after leaving it alone for a while I got an error, however this error wasn't written to the logs.

I thought this was likely due to something being wrong in the global.asax.

My original code:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((configName, configSetter) =>
        {
            string connectionString;

            if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
            {
                connectionString = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName);
            }
            else
            {
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configName];
            }


            configSetter(connectionString);
        });   
    }
```

After some trial and error I ended up with this as the final working version:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((configName, configSetter) =>
        {
            string connectionString;

            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configName];
            configSetter(connectionString);
        });   
    }
```

Now the azure plugin works as expected and all my photos are displaying nicely. I'm not sure why pulling the connection string out of the azure settings wasn't working.

I'm happy with my solution of pulling the blob storage connection though the web.config